# How can I connect to a remote mongodb server using the mongo shell?

Tags: windows, mongodb, mongo-shell

Trying to connect to a remote MongoDB server I get: `socket operation timed out`.
and the firewall log also doesn't mention any attempted connection.

I have the Mongodb running on a remote `Windows 2012` vm.
I used `--bind_ip 0.0.0.0` and added the firewall rules from the docs.
`ping`´ing from either client/server works and so does the `vnc`.
And I'm able to connect from the server using either `localhost` or the `ip`

Im new to networking and thought I slowly understand, but apparently thats not the case!

Is there anything else I did not consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your terminal

```
mongo -u <USER> -p <PASSWORD> <HOST>:<PORT>/<DB> --authenticationDatabase <AUTH_DB>
```

Comment: Did not work. I found it now tho. The firewall of the machine running the vm was blocking port 27017.